Playwright UI timeline data get wiped when test fails
I'm using playwright UI to troubleshot my E2E tests. When I'm running a test, it successfully load the timeline (middle upper-part, where you can see the browser doing its manipulations when running the tests).

But when my test fail, the timeline and actions panels suddenly get empty, I can't troubleshoot my tests because of that...

I previously used playwright 1.35.1, but needed to upgrade to fix some issues. I'm now using 1.44.0, same issue with 1.43.0.
I'm running npx playwright test --ui inside a WSL container and shell.
Thanks for your help !

I have it the same on windows without wsl. We started PW with 1.44.1 and Angular 17. Now on 1.45.0 and Angular 18 (esbuilder) it breaks. Super frustrating
